# Select2 jQuery is not being initializated after Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, jquery-select2

My issue is that I have a field that is added dynamically to my site after a button is clicked. But I am not able to load the [select2](https://select2.github.io/) data souce from an API since it seems to be loaded before it finishes or something. I've tried to use `setTimeout()`, `.delay()`, `.done()` in Ajax request and nothing happens.

```
var productos = [];

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/facturacion/productos',
        method: 'get',
        success: function (data) {
            if(data) {
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                    productos.push({
                        id: data[i].id,
                        text: data[i].descripcion
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function() {
        $(`#nombre_${articuloId}`).select2({
            data: productos,
            language: 'es'
        });
    });
```

The array *productos* can be called and the data is displayed correctly, If you have any clues I will appreciate it. Something else is that if I call the same variable productos from outside the Ajax request it removes it index.

Comment: What does `console.log(productos);` inside `then(function() {....` gives you?

Comment: it gives to me an object's array.

Comment: Does it have a proper structure like `[{ id: 0, text: 'somevalue' }, { id:1, text:'somevalue'}]` ?

Comment: Yes, its JSON formatted.